# Determine p-value if $\Theta_0$ is not singleton

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Here's what I've learned about general test problems:

> Let $X_1,\ldots X_n$ be random variables whose distributions depend on a parameter $\theta$ in some parameter space $\Theta.$
>
> A general test problem is of the form
>   $$
> H_0: \theta\in \Theta_0, H_1: \theta\in \Theta_1,
> $$
>   where $\Theta_0, \Theta_1 \subset \Theta.$
>
> A test statistic is a real valued random variable $T=T(X_1,\ldots,X_n).$
>
> After observing $T_{obs}$ we may decide to reject $H_0$ iff $T_{obs}>c$, for some real number $c \in \mathbb R.$ Then the p-value is 
>   $$P(T>T_{obs}|H_0 \text{ is true}).\tag{1}$$

As I understand it, $\Theta_0$ may have more than one element. Doesn't this make it impossible to find the p-value in some cases? Or do we always assume that $\Theta_0$ is specific enough to pin down the distribution of $T$?

Cheers!

Comment: To your second question: yes, we usually do that. All well known textbook statistics do that. To your first question: yes, a composite null hypothesis does in general mean that the null distribution of the test statistic is not determined (because it depends on which value of the null set is the true value). One can often compute a "worst case" p-value; here's an example where that is done: https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btp053

Comment: I read the textbooks differently than @Gordon.  It comes down to the fact that the p-value is defined as the *supremum* of all such probabilities $(1)$ as the distribution ranges over $H_0$.  Standard textbook examples are chosen so that this supremum occurs on the boundary of $H_0$ in the space $H_0\cup H_A$ and, although often that boundary is not a singleton, the distribution of $T$ is constant on the boundary.

Comment: @whuber that isn't a standard definition of a p-value. The general concept has more nuance than what you've described and it is important to be precise. Allow me to provide a well-known reference. Casella and Berger give a general definition of the p-value in their Statistical Inference textbook: "A p-value is a test statistic satisfying $0 \le p(x) \le 1$ for every sample point $x$." Importantly, they define a p-value to be *valid* if, for every $\theta \in \Theta_0$ and every $0 \le \alpha \le 1$, $P_\theta (p(X) \le \alpha) \le \alpha$.

Comment: @jjet Thank you for the clarification.  I sympathize with your appreciation for nuance, even if that might not be warranted in this particular context.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67396/discussion-on-question-by-epiousios-determine-p-value-if-theta-0-is-not-singl).

Comment: @whuber Just to make clear -- your supremum definition is the same as what I was refering to as a "worst case" p-value. We must read different textbooks. While the supremum definition is well known and obvious, I've never actually seen it used in a textbook. Textbook statistics (anova, t-stats etc) make heavy use of nuisance variables, which is another way to deal with multidimensional composite nulls, and not the same as taking a supremum.